# How to display thumbnail if post have one other wise don't

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to display the most recent post in a a block, and if the post is assigned with a thumbnail I would like it to be shown on the left to the post content.

This is my code that I have been trying

```
                <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1') ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail(); )?>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <p class="text-muted">Posted on <?php the_time('jS F, Y'); ?></p>
                </div>

                    } 
                <?php else;?>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <p class="text-muted">Posted on <?php the_time('jS F, Y'); ?></p>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Hope someone could help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: WordPress questions are typically offtopic, try here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be useful for you try something like :

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),'large', true);
    echo '<a href="' . $image_url[0] .'" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '">';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    echo '</a>';
        } else {
            echo 'test';
        }
?>
```